# react-TS how to hide login component if you already logged in

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know there is some posts about this but I am using react with typescript and react-router v4 beside all I want is help to make the code below works properly..

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component<{ appState: AppState }, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router children={appState}>
        <Login appState={appState} />
        <div className="main-content">
          <Home />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

loginComponent:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component<{ appState: any }, {}> {
  render() {
    return (<LoginComponent />);
  }
}
```

yeah it throws "A Router may have only one child element" exception. How can I set the condition render home component if user logged in othwerwise login component

EDITED:
AppState(mobx)

```
export class AppState {
    @observable public username: any = null
    @observable public password: any = null
    @action setUsername(username:any){
      this.username=username;
    }
    @action setPassword(password:any){
      this.password=password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you storing the "already logged" value?

Comment: @QoP edited post with this info. its stored in mobx component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt understand which one is the logined value. But your question is general "conditions" issue.

```
 const CheckLogin =  this.username==null ? "NotValid" : "Logined"
```

it should be help you to understand how you supposed to convert this code your system